# Pasting text in Word or Outlook inserts space character at wrong location

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, copy-paste, clipboard

While editing Documents in Word or typing Mails in Outlook or Chatting in Skype, I sometimes see a strange behavior in copy-paste.

Say I have the text **" assign"** in the clipboard, and put the cursor before the word **"while"**. Now when I paste, I would expect either of these:

> **" assignwhile"**, where there is no space between the two words. This is normal and WYSIWYG.
>   **" assign while"**, where an extra space between the words in automatically inserted by the application. This is some enhancement in the application to automatically put spaces where required.

But I get this:

> **" assignw hile"**, which has an automatic space, but shifted to the right.

I have seen this strange behavior for quite some time, and usually ignored it; Now I am able to undo-redo and see it consistently, hence asking here:
**What is going on ?

If this is a feature, not a bug, then how to disable it ?**

Environment:

> Windows 10 Enterprise Version 1511 with Word 2016 Version 16.0.4549.1000

UPDATE:
In Outlook, while composing a mail, I had the text "we store" with " may" in clipboard.
When I Paste between "we" and " store", I get "we may store" [[ Correct ]]
When I Paste between "we " and "store", I get "we mays tore" [[ Wrong ]]
I tried it repeatedly with same results.

I tried pasting in Notepad, where I got the correct output, but strangely, "undo" or "ctrl-z" does not remove the Pasted text !
It only selects the Pasted text ! Paste inserts " may", undo selects " may" !

I then went to PowerShell and collected some **Debug Data** about the clipboard, using "Get-Clipboard -TextFormatType [[Html,Rtf,Text,UnicodeText]]".
**Output was huge for Html+Rtf**; I have uploaded all to pastebin :
https://pastebin.com/CZUbhfST

Comment: When you do the same thing in notepad - does it behave the same way or is it specific only for Word / Outlook. Have you observed similar behaviour in other office apps like Excel / Powerpoint? One can rule out this as an OS issue if the behaviour is consistent across apps - if not it could be something wrong with the MS Office application

Comment: @Prasanna , I have seen only with Office applications, including Skype; Notepad, Putty all working fine.

Comment: I'm wondering if this could be a clipboard issue. Are you open to trying [other clipboard managers](http://windowsreport.com/clipboard-managers-windows-10/) to see if this issue persists?

Comment: @Prasanna , I am using only the built in clipboard, but it is unlikely to be the culprit , because it can not change the text in the target application. If copy-paste gave some wrong characters or it gave same behaviour in all applications , then clipboard may be a suspect.

Comment: Did you try to use the "Paste Options"? I mean, Keep Text Only.

Comment: @thims , Hmmm , no , I did not try that ; Next time I encounter this "bug" , I will try that and then update here.

Comment: @thims , even "Paste text only" shows same Issue. I will update the Q with this now.

Comment: Could it be because of the smart feature called "Adjust sentence and word spacing automatically" (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/outlook-advanced-editing-options-a861312b-b05d-421a-b5c8-9f2c6b65e751)?

Answer (score 1):

Credit belongs to @djhurio!

This worked for me.  From Microsoft Outlook 2016: File -> Options

[image]

[image]

[image]